# run function ON window resize [NOT WORKING]

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    //code
});
```

I'm using this code to update the size of elements on my website everytime the screen is resized. It works for when I resize the window while it's in small mode.

However, when I switch between fullscreen and smallscreen (using the button to the left of the X or close window button) it doesn't trigger the function.

What can I use instead of 'resize' to detect when the window switches between fullscreen.

Comment: Your above code **should** trigger on clicking `Maximise` / `Minimise`; both do indeed trigger the `resize` event. Perhaps it would help to add a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearing showcasing the problem.

Comment: Might also be useful to indicate in which browsers this is the case.

Comment: in google chrome.

Comment: Sorry, the function does trigger, however, it triggers before the window is finished resizing. Because of this, all the sizes are wrong.

Comment: Then try a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) inside the `resize` handler.

Comment: Thanks, it works when I set the Timeout to 200 miliseconds. I just don't understand why the function only triggers when the resize starts instead of triggering multiple times throughout, similar to how it does when you resize it normally.

Comment: It triggers several times. Perhaps you should use `_.debounce(() => "do stuff", 100)`?

Comment: When you resize "normaly", using a mouse drag on an edge, it fires multiple times because the browser doesn't know when you're done resizing. So that is tied to mousemove too... Which fires multiple times. Using the minimize/maximise button, there is only one event fired because the browser knows to what dimension it has to go. -- And the event is the start point for your script... So yes, it occurs BEFORE your `resize` script.